# Sum cells based on the value of other cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells

I am facing a problem that seems trivial in Excel. What I need to do is simply this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/kxZlXeo.png]

In short, I have a large file of prices linked to a few people and I need to know how much each person paid. I've tried things with VLOOKUP with not much success.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please edit your question to include the things you've tried with `vlookup`? It would help the others to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need `SUMIF()` formula.

In your specific case `=SUMIF(B$2:B$9;D4;A$2:A$9)` will give you the sum for `Name1` then paste it down for `Name2` and `Name3`

[image: Table]

Answer (score 1):

**SUMPRODUCT** function can help you get the result:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$9=E4)*($A$2:$A$9))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one @Lee,, you get perfect 10 ☺